# How do I return values from my stored procedure from SQL to c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I am storing a value which is the student reference number which I have done, not I need to return the value from my ID and my DateTime in textbox2 and textbox 3. Whilst inputting and executing the procedure.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new *****))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Exams_BagCheck_ScanIn";
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentReference", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The procedure

```
USE [IFCustom]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Exams_BagCheck_ScanIn]
        @StudentReference = N'1'

SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'

GO
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure returns nothing, you need to remove:

```
SELECT @return_value as 'Return Value'
```

And instead:

```
RETURN @return_value
```

(If you wanted to `select` then `.ExecuteScalar()` would return the value)

Answer (score 1):

If you just returning a single value then you can use

this:

```
string some_value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); // if it is string
```

OR

```
Object some_value = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // convert it to its repective type.
```

in place of

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

//`some_value` will contain the value you selected as `SELECT @return_value` in procedure.